# Trying to write a query that counts multiple things with different where cases

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help I am trying to write a query that counts multiple things with different where cases.
Here is where I got so far I was able to do separate queries, but what I am trying to do is combine them in one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Marketing"
    FROM PROJECT
    WHERE Department = 'Marketing';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of Finance"
    FROM PROJECT
    WHERE Department = 'Finance';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of Accounting"
    FROM PROJECT
    WHERE Department = 'Accounting';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT Department, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM PROJECT
WHERE Department IN  ('Marketing','Finance','Accounting')
GROUP BY Department
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. Now I see it was simple I was just making it much harder than it was.